# Kotlin/Firebase: reauthenticate() - Google Auth ERROR (Invalid id_token in IdP)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

The issue I am having is with regards to re-authentication in Android (Kotlin). My goal is to delete a user account!

I first get the current user using the following code:

```
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
```

From `user` I am able to get the token, the issue occurs during the reauthentication function call.

*At this stage, the user has already logged in. This issue is not a Google Sign In issue.* The code is as follows:

```
user.getToken(true).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        val googleIdToken = task.result.token
        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleIdToken, null)
        user.reauthenticate(credentials)?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                println("It worked")
            }else {
                println(task.exception?.localizedMessage)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting error is:

> An internal error has occurred. [ Invalid id_token in IdP
>   response:TOKEN_HERE*, error ]

*The actual token is here (long string)

Resources used:

- [reauthenticate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user)
- [GoogleAuthProvider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/GoogleAuthProvider)
- [Verify ID Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens)

The have checked the `google-service.json` and all the ID's match firebase. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: see if this helps https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/vDTR3sBmHKg

Comment: Hi @Tauqir, thank you for your reply! Unfortunately that didn't work,  only have one project